# Opencart Custom Registration Fields(CRF) deserialised to database values

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to de-serialised Opencart Custom Registration Fields(CRF) from database value.

for Example : `a:3:{i:14;a:1:{i:0;s:2:"60";}i:15;s:0:"";i:13;s:2:"59";}`

```
Response should be in key and value pair
key1=>"values",
key2=>"values",
key3=>"values",
key4=>"values"
```

Please help me here.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

Please check below code:

```
$arr = 'a:3:{i:14;a:1:{i:0;s:2:"60";}i:15;s:0:"";i:13;s:2:"59";}';
$arry = unserialize($arr);
$ids = array_keys($arry);
print_r($ids);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

a:3:{i:14;a:1:{i:0;s:2:"54";}i:15;s:0:"";i:13;s:2:"59";}

Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 54
        )

    [15] => 
    [13] => 59
)
Can you please about more ?
associated array key and value pairs values.

Comment: how can I get the actual values corresponding the each ids (14,15,13)?
from Opencart database.

Comment: So you want `'14' => 54, '15' => '', '13' => 59` right?

Comment: I don't know about the opencart database structure also I don't know where Opencart DB store the Custom Registration Fields columns name and them values.

If you know please help me.

Comment: I can't figure out what you want to do? You want to store this value in opencart db in new table or do you want to store this value in existing table. If you want to store that value in new table then create new table in your db.

Comment: I want to retrieve that from Opencart database.
Columns stored the values is 'a:3:{i:14;a:1:{i:0;s:2:"60";}i:15;s:0:"";i:13;s:2:"59";}'

I have unserialize with your help, now I want to get the unserialized ids(14,15,13) values from database not ids that we got.

Comment: If you want to get `ids(14,15,13)` from `unserialize` data than see my edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79192/discussion-between-singh-and-hardik-solanki).